# convert java app to mac installer...dmg

Tags: java, macos, dmg

I would like to know do we have any software to convert java app i mean .jar file to .dmg file (installer for mac).Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

A .dmg file is *not* an installer, it's a [disk image file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image).  If you want to make something available for distribution, the easiest way is to create a new folder (directory), copy all of the files and folders you want to distribute into it, and then use either the OS X [Disk Utility](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/os-x/creating-disk-images-with-disk-utility/) application (in /Applications/Utilities) or the command line [hdiutil](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) utility to create a new disk image file from the contents of the folder.

Comment: +1 for hdiutil. There's an ant example here: http://robotchase.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/robotchase/trunk/build.xml?revision=66&view=markup

Answer (score 3):

Use "Jar Bundler" in the XCode download from Apple Developer Connection.

http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html

You will need to register for a free account.

---

Steps: http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Macify Maven Plugin](https://github.com/nebulorum/macify).

Comment: That is not an installer.