# Convert .Jar to .Dmg

Tags: java, macos, jar

I have a java application with jar file and a lib folder to go with it,and i want to bundle my application along with the lib files and folders into a .DMG file to run on MAC OS x so if anybody has a similar experience please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [convert java app to mac installer…dmg
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174849/convert-java-app-to-mac-installer-dmg).

Comment: See new documentation by Oracle for Java 9: [*Self-Contained Application Packaging*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG583)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put all your files in one folder together. Then you open the Disk Utility (Applications -> Utilities -> Disk Utility) and choose "New Image from folder..."

That's all.

Comment: cannot open jar file once u New  Image From

Comment: @Sheldon Select the folder where your .jar file is inside - not the jar file itself

Answer (score 4):

You might want to make a dmg disk image from the makefile/build file:

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder <directory> <dmg_file_name>.dmg
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **javapackager tool** to build the you_app.app application and wrap it into an installer:

```
mkdir -p package/macosx
cp you_icon_app.icns package/macosx
jdk=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
$jdk/bin/javapackager -version
$jdk/bin/javapackager -deploy -native dmg \
   -srcfiles you_app.jar -appclass you_app_name -name you_app_name \
   -outdir deploy -outfile you_app_name -v
cp deploy/bundles/you_app_name-1.0.dmg you_app_name-installer.dmg
```

And done.

Answer (score 1):

I use a maven plugin: [osxappbundle-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/osxappbundle-maven-plugin/)