# Run a Java application on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

i am currently developing an application on my Windows laptop however I also need it to run on a Mac. Is there a way to either convert my project to .dmg or .app or create a mac build striaght from Windows Eclipse?

I would very much rather not have to install Eclipse on the Mac machine just for this as it is a one time thing. Any Suggestions?

Comment: You need only the [JRE](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp#mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experiences you need a Mac to create anything for the Mac/iOS platform. So I guess you need a mac to create a dmg file.

Here is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395948/convert-jar-to-dmg) that says how this can be accomplished.

Of course you can just run the jar from the command line.

Comment: I did think of the jar from the command line however it will be used by a very computer illiterate person so would like to keep it as simple as possible to run! I will have a look at that link. Thanks

Comment: When you want to run the jar you can create a shell script that executes the command. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking)

Comment: Accepted you answer as will probably go for the scripting method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

run on any Java virtual machine. It does not matter if you run it on a mac or pc, that's the whole idea with java

Answer (score 1):

Any simple way of creating a dmg file will probably require a Mac, however you don't need to do that; after all, you don't create an exe when you run a Java program on Windows either. Instead export it as a jar file and it should work on both systems (provided a Java Runtime Environment is installed and is set to run jar filed).

If you insist on creating a dmg, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform) which discusses creating them on Windows.