# How can I wrap a JAR into a Windows and Mac Executable (.exe, .jar)?

Tags: java, .app

I have searched hours and hours for a wrapper program that can create executables from jar and runs on mac.

Seraching on stackoverflow etc there were only deprecated solutions such as javabundler, appbundler, packr, jar2app. I tried all of them but they do not work.

**Is there a simple program that can create executables for at least Windows and Mac OS X** and runs on them as well?

Comment: May duplicated to [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file), but still suggest give [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) a try

Comment: Launch4j only creats exe. I also need to prpvide app for mac OS X

Comment: You mean create a dmg?

Comment: [Convert .Jar to .Dmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395948/convert-jar-to-dmg) there are some approaches.

Comment: Try using [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm)