# How to convert jar file to DMG from windows Operating System

Tags: java, windows, jar, dmg

I had Developed Java Application in Windows 7.

And I had made JAR file of that application.

Now I want to convert that File into DMG format which is compatible for MAC Operating System.

Can any one Suggest me steps please?

I tried into terminal But got this errors.

```
DEVs-MacBook-Proist idev$ java -jar Soul_Spotter.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: idev/soulspotter/Login : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: But `jar` is compatible for Mac too.

Comment: I had tried to use tha JAR file to MAC OS but cant succeeded. :(

Comment: Search for "windows create dmg" - you can put the JAR *in* an [Apply Disk Image (DMG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image), but if you can't run the JAR by itself, it won't run if you put it in a DMG either.

Comment: Let me guess: You tried with double-click? Try to execute it via terminal command: `java -jar yourJar.jar`

Comment: jar is compatible for Mac too buddy

Comment: But I have exzatly no idea how to do this. I had tried to search for this already.

Comment: Terminal command... Try it.

Comment: Ok I am trying. Thanks.

Comment: I got the error. See my Edited Question

Comment: Now, that's another question. At least it will work if program is correctly written.

Comment: I have whole project which contain Numbers of class files, but It successfully Run on Window OS. But it doesn't run in MAC OS.

Comment: @NiravDabhi So fix that (learn how to correctly run the JAR on OS X), *without* worrying about a DMG.

Comment: Google `UnsupportedClassVersionError` - that normally means the class was compiled for a newer version of Java than you are attempting to run with

Comment: We had made the application in JDK 1.7 and the Version of MAC is JDK 1.6. Is this error cause of this?

Comment: Yes, either upgrade your Mac or when you compile include the `-target` as described in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: can you tell me how to write the command prompt "-target" with example please?

Answer (score 0):

The below link explains the steps. I've also copied the answer which worked for me.

Copied from [convert java app to mac installer...dmg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174849/convert-java-app-to-mac-installer-dmg?rq=1)

> Use "Jar Bundler" in the XCode download from Apple Developer
>   Connection.
>
> http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html
>
> You will need to register for a free account.
>
> Steps: http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/